# Only was able to recover MySQL data folder (IBD, FRM, and OPT files), can I recover databases?

Tags: mysql, recover, frm

As title says, I had an unfortunate failure which resulted in me only being able to recover my MySQL data folder (IBD, FRM, and OPT files). I built a new server and installed MySQL 5.6 (old one used 5.5). I copied over the data folder hoping I would get lucky, and I do see my old schemas in MySQL workbench, but when trying to look at any table in them I get an error like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q2eui8eyu621f3c/sqlerror.jpg?dl=0

I don't remember seeing any .data files on the recovered data and am wondering if it's possible for me to recover my old tables. I'm not sure whether or not the old or new is InnoDB or myisam and am not exactly sure how to tell.

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else who doesn't know how to restore their databases runs into a similar issue, I was able to recover my data. Instead of copying and pasting everything in which did not work, I stopped the MySQL service, pasted all the database folders in, and only the "ibdata1" file. Then I restarted the service and loaded up workbench and all my data as restored in 5.6.